# local storage Overwriting issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, web

i have been working on quiz app where i am only allowed to use javaScript. the app works like i ask user to chose username and i save it in variable and he/she starts answering and the score gets higher and higher and being saved in score variable as well. later on once the game finishes i am printing the message and have to present the 5 top score users. for that purpose i am using local storage, the problem is when i save the data it works fine but when i restart or play again the data is being overwritten. for example first user name being replaced with newer player. my code for saving the data is ;

```
      var obj = convertUserAndScore(user, score);
      var players = new Array;

      players.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.score - b.score;
      });


      players.push(JSON.stringify(obj));

      localStorage.setItem("players", players);


      function convertUserAndScore(user, score) {

         return { "usename": user , "score": score};
      }
```

Comment: What is the trigger that cause new player to be written to the local storage?

Comment: actually when user submits the answer it goes to server ans server sends back the new question with a new URL in json object so we check when there are no new URL it mean game is over there i trigger for local storage and i already asked the username from user and calculated the score so i am passing the username and score in the parameters.

Comment: try to provide some more code, this will help us to help you

Comment: i dont know where to sen you the code. and i cant share all of my code here since its the assignment and my teachers cheack for the pilgrims

Comment: Please write in standard international English, in which the first word of sentences is capitalized, and the word "I" is also capitalized, and there is no space before punctuation such as `:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems.

First you always initialize an empty array...and never get the stored data from localStorage

Next you take that empty array and store it in localStorage right away. This would definitely overwrite any other time you actually store an array with length

Third you are stringifying the elements in array when you need to stringify the whole array

---

Lets start with page load:

```
var localData = localStorage.getItem("players");
// if defined then parse stored data or use empty array
var players = localData ? JSON.parse(localData ) : [];
```

Now when you do something to change array you need to stringify the whole thing

```
var somObj= //...
players.push(somObj);
localStorage.setItem("players", JSON.stringify(players));
```

Comment: hmm what do you mean by " First you always initialize an empty array...and never get the stored data from localStorage "? do you mean i shouldnt initialize    var players = new Array;? than where should i initialize my array?

Comment: and i dont understand this line var players = localData ? JSON.parse(localData ) || []; and it gives an error in my code. and just so you know i am not allowed to use any libraries like jquiry or anything

Comment: it is a **[ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)** conditional .... basically `if(localData){ players = JSON.parse(localData );}{ else players = []}`

Comment: thanks! that error was removed but now it says app.js:151 Uncaught TypeError: players.push is not a function xhr.onreadystatechange @ app.js:15. and not updating the local storage

Comment: thanks man its working now, but a minor problem is still left that the stored data is not sorted this function players.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.score - b.score;
      }); is no longer working